# How to read JSON data from flat file in Informatica cloud platform?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, flat-file, informatica-cloud, iics

I have a flat file(.txt) generated from a web service having the contents something as below:

**Field1**        Field2

**""key1": [{"somekey":"somevalue"}], "key2": "somevalue2"**       testvalueforfield2

As you can see from above structure Field1 of my flat file contains a JSON based response. I want the JSON response to be extracted and written to a .json file. I'm not able to extract the JSON response from my flat file. Can anyone help me so as to which transformations and/or components I must use to get this done ?

**Update:** I'm using a hierarchy parser to extract fields from my json value present in flat file but nothing comes up in the target file

Comment: A bit more info might be needed. Is that a response from some REST service? Do you get a file or a response? Are you using Data Integration (CDI) module, or Application Integration (CAI) module?

Comment: @Maciejg I'm using a rest connection inside a business service and using that I am able to generate above response to a flat file. I'm using a Data Integration module currently

Comment: Rather than extracting from a file you could pass the rest response to Hierarchy Parser that would parse it and give you the values. If you NEED to read from a file, that is a different problem - as Data Integration will read the file line-by-line, basically cutting your JSON to pieces. To avoid that you'd need to set the line delimeter to some non-existing string, havig full JSON in single field as a result.

Comment: I tried this. However I receive an error in my job as [ERROR] Failed to process data: parse error: Syntax error while parsing ':'-. The job is a success but 0 rows are processed. Also the preview for hierarchy parser is empty.